# Trig Problem. Find the angle.

Tags: trigonometry

I've spent hours on this problem now and I can't figure it out. :( I would very much appreciate some help. Thank you!

A soccer field has a rectangular penalty area that measures 136 feet by 51 feet. The goal is 24 feet wide and centered along the back of the penalty area. Assume the goalkeeper can block a shot 6 feet to either side of their position for a total coverage of 12 feet.

A penalty kick is taken from a corner of the penalty area at position A (see the figure below). The goalkeeper stands 6 feet from the goalpost nearest the shooter and can thus block a shot anywhere between the middle of the goal and the nearest goalpost (segment CD). To score, the shooter must kick the ball within the angle CAE. Find the measure of this angle to the nearest tenth of a degree. Assume a = 56 feet and b = 51 feet.

This is the image associated with the problem:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/N3620.gif

Comment: $ \ AC \ $ and $ \ AE \ $ are the hypotenuses of right triangles with the right angle at the corner $ \ B \ $ .  You are given the length of the leg $ \ AB \ $ and you can calculate the lengths of legs $ \ BC \ $ and $ \ BE \ $ for each right triangle.  That will allow you to find the size of angles $ \ BAC \ $ and $ \ BAE \ $ for each triangle.  You want the difference in the size of those angles, which gives the measure of angle $ \ CAE \ $ .

Comment: Thank you! The answer is 4.4 degrees. Huzzah!

Answer (score 1):

$CAE=EAB-CAB$. The last two are angles in right triangles you have both legs of, so use $\arctan$